# Cambiar un simbolo con expresiones regulares

Tags: r, regex

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente df:

```
df<-data.frame(col1=c("23","-23", "23-25","123-125","-134","3-500","30-500","3-4"))
```

```
     col1
1      23
2     -23
3   23-25
4 123-125
5    -134
6   3-500
7  30-500
8     3-4
```

Quiero quitar el guión cuando va delante de un número que no es un intervalo, es decir
-23 lo cambio por 23, pero 23-25 lo dejo tal cual.

Con lo que el df quedaría así:

```
     col1
1      23
2      23
3   23-25
4 123-125
5     134
6   3-500
7  30-500
8     3-4
```

Había pensado hacerlo en tres pasadas:

- Busco número-número y lo cambio por número/número.
- Luego borro todos los -
- Luego cambio / por -

He probado con str_replace y con sub haciendo variantes de esto, pero nada

```
df$col1<-sub("\\d{1,}\\-\\d{1,}", "\\d{1,} \\/ \\d{1,}", df$col1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando expresiones regulares puedes probar si el primer carácter es `"-"` con `"^[-]"` y remplazar estos casos con  `""`

```
df<-data.frame(col1=c("23","-23","23-25","123-125","-134","3-500"),strinsAsFactor=F)
sub("^[-]","",df$col1)
[1] "23"      "23"      "23-25"   "123-125" "134"     "3-500"
```

Answer (score 2):

- Que no esté precedido por un dígito: `(?<!\d)`
- Que esté seguido por un dígito: `(?=\d)`

Eliminar guiones:

```
gsub("(?<!\\d)-(?=\\d)", "", df$col1, perl=TRUE)
```